# Conditional deleting several columns with R

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have several columns X1, X2, X3, X4, X5. How can I write "." in rows in X1, X2 and X3, for which X4=10 or X4=15?

Comment: Consider posting the code you have tried so far, along with an example data set and the desired answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward.  Here's an example with some fake data.

```
> d <- data.frame(X1 = 1:5, X2 = 6:10, X3 = 10:14)
> d
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  6 10
# 2  2  7 11
# 3  3  8 12
# 4  4  9 13
# 5  5 10 14
```

Now, if the column `X3` equals 10 or 14, replace the first two columns of the same row(s) with `.`

```
> d[d$X3 == 10 | d$X3 == 14, 1:2] <- "."
> d
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  .  . 10
# 2  2  7 11
# 3  3  8 12
# 4  4  9 13
# 5  .  . 14
```